# Cypress not matching routes in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I've successfully mocked several routes in testing this application. My recent work involved making a GET request on the app's startup.

```js
export const requestSettings = () =>
  dispatch => {
    console.log('Requesting settings');

    const url = urls.SETTINGS_HTTP;
    axios.get(url)
      .then(res => {
        console.log('response from axios');
        return dispatch(updateSettingsFromBackend(res.data));
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log('axios error', e, e.config);
        return dispatch(reportError('Request for initial settings failed.'));
      });
  };
```

In Cypress I mocked this route which allowed all my tests to run (since otherwise they'd fail on the failed HTTP request at the start of each test):

```js
// commands.js
const urls = buildUrls(Cypress.env()); // we don't have the window yet
const settingsHttpUrl = urls.SETTINGS_HTTP;
const initialSettingsForTest = { ...defaultSettingsState, displayProgressIndicator: true };
const initialPayloadForTests = _createSettingsApiPayload(initialSettingsForTest);

Cypress.Commands.add("mockGetSettings", (code: number = 200) =>
  cy.route({
    method: 'GET',
    url: settingsHttpUrl,
    status: code,
    response: code === 200 ? initialPayloadForTests : {},
  }));

Cypress.Commands.add("mockPutSettings", (code: number) =>
  cy.route({
    method: 'PUT',
    url: settingsHttpUrl,
    status: code,
    response: {},
  }));

// the tests
describe('updating settings (requestParameterChange)', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      cy.mockGetSettings(200);
      cy.visitSettings();
    });

   ...
```

This worked fine.

My latest branch involves waiting to make this initial request until a certain websocket message is received. In my cypress tests I am able to dispatch that websocket handler to get the sequence going and ultimately call the same GET endpoint. With my back-end running, I am able to do this in the live app. The implementation is there.

However, in this branch, my mock is just not working! With the back-end up, the functionality works (which means it's hitting the real back-end, not the mock), and with the back-end down, it fails (because the mock isn't being hit).

```js
describe('Settings Page', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.server();
    cy.clock();
  });

  describe('initial state', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      cy.mockGetSettings(200).as('getRequest');
      cy.visitSettings();
    });

    it('starts in a waiting state, with no settings.', () => {
      cy.contains('Waiting for settings...');
    });

    it.only('requests the settings when it receives a FIRMM status message', () => {
      const message = { data: JSON.stringify({ status: 10 }) } as MessageEvent;
      cy.dispatch(handleStatusMessage(message));
      cy.wait('@getRequest');
    });
```

(Note, by the way, the `mockPutSettings` command earlier in this post, which DOES WORK.)

`cy.wait('@getRequest')` fails with

> CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms for the 1st request to the route: 'getRequest'. No request ever occurred.

Chrome console shows: `GET http://localhost:5000/settings/ net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

In fact, taking the app itself out of the equation also fails:

```js
    it('requests the settings when it receives a FIRMM status message', () => {
      cy.visit(url);
      cy.wait('@getRequest');
    });
```

In the cypress window, we can see that the route is being created/set up, but it doesn't get hit.
[image]

What's happening?

PS. `axios-mock-adapter` DOES work for this:

```js
function mockGet() {
  // ... setup of constants as before ...
  return new MockAdapter(axios).onGet(settingsHttpUrl).reply(() => {
    console.log('MOCK AXIOS HIT');
    return [200, initialPayloadForTests];
  });
}

describe('Settings Page', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.server();
    cy.clock();
    mock = mockGet();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    mock.restore();
  });
```

The tests work, the response comes, `MOCK AXIOS HIT` prints to the console. However, `mock.history.get` is empty.